# Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression error

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb

I'm getting an `Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression: (PlaceManager pm) => pm.FreePlaces.get_Item(index)` error when trying to remove value from database (Mongo DB).

Here's my code:

```
var result = _placeManager.Update(Query.EQ("_id", 0),
                             Update<PlaceManager>.Pull(pm => pm.FreePlaces[index], placeId));
```

And here's `PlaceManager` class:

```
public class PlaceManager
{
    [BsonId]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CurrentSize { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, List<int>> FreePlaces { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I think it's to do with the fact that you are trying to use a function (in this case []) as part of the query and the MongoDB driver doesn't know how to serialise that function for use by the database.

Comment: any solutions to this?

Comment: @brimble2010 Did you figure out a workaround?

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot unfortunately not

Comment: A work around that I found regarding this is:
BsonDocument bsonDoc= BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>("{key:value}");
var builder = Builders<MyClass>.Filter.And(
                        bsonDoc)